# Why doesn't re.compile(rf"(\b{re.escape('g(x)')}\b)+",re.I) find the string 'g(x)'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

I ran the following code in python 3.8

```
import re

a,b,c = 'g(x)g', '(x)g', 'g(x)'
a_re = re.compile(rf"(\b{re.escape(a)}\b)+",re.I)
b_re = re.compile(rf"(\b{re.escape(b)}\b)+",re.I)
c_re = re.compile(rf"(\b{re.escape(c)}\b)+",re.I)

a_re.findall('g(x)g')
b_re.findall('(x)g')
c_re.findall('g(x)')
c_re.findall(' g(x) ')
```

The result I want is below.

```
['g(x)g']
['(x)g']
['g(x)']
['g(x)']
```

But the actual result is below.

```
['g(x)g']
[]
[]
[]
```

The following conditions must be observed:

```
A combination of variables and f-string should be used.
\b must not be removed.
```

Because I want to know if there are certain characters in the sentence.

How can I get the results I want?

---

Regular characters have no problem using \b, but it won't work for words that start with '(' or end with ')'.

I was wondering if there is an alternative to \b that can be used in these words.

I must use the same function as \b because I want to make sure that the sentence contains a specific word.

Comment: By removing `\b`?

Comment: \b must not be removed.

Comment: `\b` matches the boundary between a word character, and a non-word character (or either end of the string).  If your pattern starts or ends with a non-word character, then you are REQUIRING that there be a word character in that direction.  Basically `\b` only makes sense when placed next to word characters.

Comment: I need to use `\b` because I want to find 'g(x)' and not 'gg(x)' in the sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own `\b` by finding start, end, or separator and not capturing it

- `(^|[ .\"\'])` start or boundary
- `($|[ .\"\'])` end or boundary
- `(?:)` non-capture group

```py
>>> a_re = re.compile(rf"(?:^|[ .\"\'])({re.escape(a)})(?:$|[ .\"\'])", re.I)
>>> b_re = re.compile(rf"(?:^|[ .\"\'])({re.escape(b)})(?:$|[ .\"\'])", re.I)
>>> c_re = re.compile(rf"(?:^|[ .\"\'])({re.escape(c)})(?:$|[ .\"\'])", re.I)
>>> a_re.findall('g(x)g')
['g(x)g']
>>> b_re.findall('(x)g')
['(x)g']
>>> c_re.findall('g(x)')
['g(x)']
>>> c_re.findall(' g(x) ')
['g(x)']
```

Comment: It's not a complete alternative because you have to allow for the possibility that the value returned by findall() will be different than when using \b, but it's a good alternative because it allows you to check if a sentence contains certain characters.

Comment: @YUNO _it depends_, but as `\b` implies `\w` you cannot pre/post-fix with a non-`\w` or would prefer that (and see your original result)! anecdotally, you may also find that string building with `+` is easier to work with than f-strings when building a regex

Answer (score 1):

`\b` is the boundary between `\w` and `\W` characters ([Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)). That is why your first one gives the result (since it starts and ends with characters) but none of the others.

To get the expected result, your patterns should look like these:

```py
a_re = re.compile(rf"(\b{re.escape(a)}\b)+",re.I)  # No change
b_re = re.compile(rf"({re.escape(b)}\b)+",re.I)  # No '\b' in the beginning
c_re = re.compile(rf"(\b{re.escape(c)})+",re.I)  # No '\b' in the end
```

Comment: The following conditions must be observed.
(1) A combination of variables and f-string should be used.
(2) \b must not be removed.

Comment: Because I want to know if there are certain characters in the sentence.

Comment: Is there no such thing as `\b` that can be used in words that start with '(' or end with ')'?